# loop in Django template: how to control the loop iterator?

Tags: django, loops, django-templates

I'm using Django to show a list of posts. Each post has a 'is_public' field, so if one post's 'is_public' equals to False, it should not be shown to the user. Also, I want to show a fixed number of posts in one page, but this number can be changing depending on views.

I decided to crop the queryset in template as a few views are using the same template, generating it in the view means a lot of repeated codes.

If written in python, it should look like this:

```
i=number_of_posts_to_show_in_one_page
while i:
  if qs[i].is_public == True:
    #show qs[i] to the page
    i--
```

As the django template does not support while loop and for loop seems hard to control, is there a way of achieving this? Or should I do it in another way?(One idea is to crop the qs before looping)Thanks!

**Update:**

I've written this template tag to pre-process the queryset:

```
    @register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
    def pre_process_list(context,list,numbers):
        #if not user.has_perm('admin'):
        context['result_list']=list.filter(is_public=True, is_removed=False)[0:numbers]
        #else:
        #context['result_list']=list[0:numbers]
        return ''
```

Before using for loop in the template, I'll pass the queryset to this templage tag, and use a simple for loop to show its result.

If in the future I want to show non-public posts to admins(which is not decided yet), I can write in some logic like the commented ones, and have them styled differently in the template.

Comment: You'd better construct the right QuerySet in your view. Such logic belongs there, and is a lot more manageable.

Comment: The template will be used by a number of views, so I'd rather not repeating myself again and again in these views. Also, originally I had the idea of showing the non-public ones to administrators, that's why I didn't want to crop the queryset before hand. That may be too complicated, so never mind

Answer (score 3):

```
{% for post in posts %}
  {% if post.is_public %}
    {{ post }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Though this would be a perfect use case for a [manager](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/feb/25/managers/).

You could write a simple manager that filters public posts.

```
class PublicPostManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(PublicPostManager, self).get_query_set().filter(is_public=True)
```

Then you would add it to your `Post` Class:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    public = PublicPostManager()
```

Then you could pass `post.public.all()` as `public_posts` to your template and simplify your loop:

```
{% for post in public_posts %}
   {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

@arie has a good approach with the manager, but you can easily do the same without writing a manager:

```
# View
posts = Post.objects.filter(is_public=True) # or use the manager
# Now, you can either limit the number of posts you send
# posts = posts[:5] (only show five in the view)
return render_to_response('foo.html',{'posts':posts})

# Template
# Or you can do the limits in your template itself:
{% for post in posts|slice:":5" %}
   {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

See the [slice filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice) on more information.

However, since this is a common operation, with django 1.3 you can use [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#multiple-object-mixins) to automate most of this.